# Linux Biolinum O messes up moderncv Package

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, rules, moderncv

Take the `template.tex` example file from http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples and add these two lines:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Linux Biolinum O}
```

Then run it with `lualatex`. Suddenly these thick bars get really slim. Why is that?

[image: change in line thickness]

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}  
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}

\moderncvstyle{casual}        
\moderncvcolor{blue}          
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resum√© title (optional)}               
\address{street and number}{postcode city}   

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}


\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}             

\end{document}
```

Comment: Minimal Example: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/zVgB7cbSWD

Comment: Weird, your mwe looks fine for me with either Biolinum or Libertine.

Comment: Now im confused. I use MacOSx & TexShop (MacTex Bundle). Simply switching from Lulatex (wired slim bar) to Xelatex (everythings fine) causes the difference.

Comment: This has nothing to do with `moderncv` in particular.  I've posted a minimal example as an answer (although it's not exactly.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a more minimal example. The problem is that LuaTeX and XeTeX use different methods for finding fonts, and as a result, LuaTeX is finding the version of the font which is in `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/` while XeLaTeX is finding the font in `/Library/Fonts`.  If we load the font using its actual filename (which is possible with LuaTeX) the correct behaviour can be seen depending on the name of the font:

Given that the version in TeXLive is *newer* than the one (that I have) in `/Library/Fonts/`, it seems that the newer font is the one with  the incorrect behaviour.

```
% !TEX TS-program = LuaLaTeX


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}    
\fontspec{LinBiolinum_Re-0.6.4}
Biolinum in \texttt{/Library/Fonts}

\rule{1in}{1ex}
\rule{1in}{4.5pt}

\fontspec{LinBiolinum_R}
Biolinum in \texttt{/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertine/}

\rule{1in}{1ex}
\rule{1in}{4.5pt}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Works fine for me, but I remember that there was a libertine version where the ex-values were faulty.

Comment: @Ulrike What versions of the fonts do you have?

Comment: @Alan Thanks, that clarifies a lot. Wicked thing is that the texlive2011 version appears to be the newest. The newest package (LinLibertineOTF_5.1.3_2011_06_21.tgz) from sourceforge shows up in Apples Font Book as -> FontForge 2.0 : Linux Biolinum O : 21-6-2011. And this version results in the thin/thick effect.

Comment: Apparently the problem persists for quite a while now. This might come in handy: http://latex-my.blogspot.de/2011/10/fixing-biolinum-font-in-beamer.html

Answer (score 5):

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Biolinum O}
```

If you have an old TeX system (for instance, TeX Live 2009), you may need to change it into

```
\setsansfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Linux Biolinum O}
```

The `Ligatures=TeX` option makes XeTeX recognize the standard ligatures `--` `---` ``` `` ``` `''` and some others.

Comment: Ah tanks, yet i actually care about the blue line besides the blue text. With other fonts it stays thick, yet gets really slim with Biolinum.

Comment: @bioslime Please, add a minimal example of code.

Comment: Just added @ my first post. Simply change the font from "Linux Biolinum O" to e.g. "Linux Libertine O" and see the difference.