# Libertine italic sans-serif missing

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, libertine

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and installed the Ubuntu package 'texlive-fonts-extra' to be able to use the Libertine font. Everything is working fine except  the sans-serif (Linux Biolinum) italic font. I get the following warnings:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/fxb/m/sl' undefined

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/fxb/m/it' undefined

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

I've found several suggestions, but none of them helped.

First of all this [Q&A](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21984/emph-yields-bold-italic-using-the-package-libertine) suggests to update the Libertine font to version 5.1.3. Well the package ttf-linux-libertine is of version 5.1.3, but I doubt that this package is used by LaTeX. I couldn't figure out which version is used by LaTeX or how to upgrade the font.

[This mail](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2010-May/025653.html) suggests to use

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

Unfortunately this does not help either.

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
    \textsf{Lorem }

    \textsf{\emph{Ipsum}}
\end{document}
```

Compare the output with and without Libertine package:
[image: With Libertine, italic broken]
[image: Without Libertine using default font, italic working]

Comment: Have you considered using `libertineotf` (with XeTeX or LuaTeX)?

Comment: Thanks! This might be a work-a-round. But it seems as if I didn't manage yet to install the OTF font correctly. I get an error `Requested font "LinLibertine_R" at 10.0pt
! Font \zf@basefont=LinLibertine_R at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file or
 installed font not found`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as suggested in many anweres and posts you should seriously consider to upgrade to a recent version of texlive. Ubuntu 12.04 is still shipped with Texlive 2009. Upgrading to 2012 solved all problems I described in my Question above.

I used [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~texlive-backports/+archive/ppa): ppa:texlive-backports/ppa

Afterwards just update all packages (this means to download like ~1GB of package data and it takes also some while to process all the necessary changes).

Only problem: now I am suffering from [this bug](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48855/linux-biolinum-o-messes-up-moderncv-package).